# How can I format percentages in Excel so that they stay percentages on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, excel, formatting

I have a report built in Excel.  One of the summary columns is presented as a percentage.  This works fine.  Unless you open the file on a mobile phone.  Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: use a different excel viewer?

Comment: I cannot ask this group to use a different Excel viewer.  It will have to be solved on my end.

Comment: output as a strings, then. `'12.34%` will show up as 12.34% no matter what, because it's no longer a number.

Comment: What mobile app are you using to as a viewer?

Answer (score 0):

use polaris office to view excel reports

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/polaris-office-for-pdf-+-microsoft/id698070860?mt=8